# How to bundle run-time-only dependencies from NuGet packages in Inno Setup installer?

Tags: nuget, installation, inno-setup

I'm creating an installer for a program that has a couple of run-time dll dependencies. These dependencies are available as NuGet packages. I was wondering if I could somehow specify the list of NuGet packages to Inno Setup, such that it will download the packages and bundles the corresponding dll's in my installer?

If that is not possible, what is the intended way to bundle such run-time only dll's from a NuGet package in an installer?

Comment: Do you want to download them on compile-time or install-time? What do you mean by "run-time-only dependency"?

Comment: They need to be downloaded when creating the installer, such that they can be bundled. So that is after compiling my application but during the creation process of my installer. When the installer is executed to install my app, the dll's should be contained in the installer, like all other parts of my app. With run-time-only I mean that there are no assemblies needed to compile my application. So, there is no need that nuget add/changes assembly references and such.

Comment: OK, and would you explain us your use case? I assume you already have the DLLs on your machine for testing. So what do you need NuGet for exactly? For an automatic build?

Comment: We are internally migrating to nuget, such that our different dev teams will deliver their sw as nuget packages in our internally managed nuget feed. Sometimes dll's are only loaded at runtime. We used some tricks and scripts in the past to copy these dll's to the output folder and have Inno Setup pick them up. With nuget we want to get rid of these scripts and declare to Inno Setup the nuget packages it should also bundle. This seems like a use case that others may also be interested in: and therefore something that Inno Setup might want so support.

Comment: OK, but NuGet is rather complex system. It do not only deliver DLLs. Are you only interested in the DLLs (contents of `lib` folder of the NuGet package) or the other NuGet stuff too?

Comment: At the moment I'm primarily interested in dlls, but in general I'm interested in everything as long as it is run-time related. Wouldn't this be a useful feature, to use nuget packages for specifying (external, meaning not present in my app's source tree) run-time dependencies of my app to Inno Setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Inno Setup preprocessor](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/) to run [`nuget.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-exe-cli-reference) to download a package and generate `[Files]` section entries based on the downloaded contents.

For example the following defines `NuGetPackage` preprocessor macro that collects all files in `lib\net45` folder of the downloaded package:

```
#pragma parseroption -p-

#define ProcessFile(Source, FindResult, FindHandle) \
    FindResult \
        ? \
            Local[0] = FindGetFileName(FindHandle), \
            Local[1] = Source + "\\" + Local[0], \
            "Source: \"" + Local[1] + "\"; DestDir: \"{app}\"\n" + \
                ProcessFile(Source, FindNext(FindHandle), FindHandle) \
        : \
            ""

#define NuGetPackage(Name) \
    Exec("nuget.exe", "install " + Name, SourcePath, , SW_HIDE), \
    Local[0] = FindFirst(AddBackslash(SourcePath) + Name + "*", faDirectory), \
    Local[0] \
        ? \
            Local[1] = FindGetFileName(Local[0]), \
            Local[2] = AddBackslash(SourcePath) + Local[1], \
            Local[3] = Local[2] + "\\lib\\net45", \
            Local[4] = FindFirst(Local[3] + "\\*", 0), \
            ProcessFile(Local[3], Local[4], Local[4]), \
        : \
            ""

#pragma parseroption -p+
```

You can use it like:

```
[Files]
#emit NuGetPackage("NUnit")
#emit NuGetPackage("EntityFramework")
```

To get:

```
[Files]
Source: "C:\source\path\NUnit.3.8.1\lib\net45\nunit.framework.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "C:\source\path\NUnit.3.8.1\lib\net45\nunit.framework.xml"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "C:\source\path\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "C:\source\path\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "C:\source\path\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.SqlServer.xml"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "C:\source\path\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.xml"; DestDir: "{app}"
```

Comment: This looks like a great solution. Thanks for sharing!