# Find a directory using wildcard in Inno Setup

Tags: nuget, installation, inno-setup, nuget-package

I'm trying to get all the files in a directory recursively while using wildcard within the name of the directory in Inno Setup script.

I have came across examples for filename but none for a directory search.

Use Case:
Basically, we have moved to using NuGet packages for our internal development projects. So each project makes a NuGet package which can be consumed by other project and/or developer.

Part of this we wish to use the Inno Setup to use the dlls and/or files from a NuGet package.

For example, we need to find the package folder matching `"../packages/PackagesA.../"`, e.g. `"PackageA v1.2.0"`.

Came across this [How to bundle run-time-only dependencies from NuGet packages in Inno Setup installer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46562537/850848), which is almost exactly I want but it seems the code doesn't work in my Inno Script.

Any help or suggestion as how to approach this?

Comment: So You do not to "find" directory. You want to include a directory into an installer that matches a certain pattern, right?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Yes that correct. Basically I want to find the NuGet package folder and its files given by just a package name. See edit above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an [Inno Setup preprocessor](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/) function that will resolve the directory file mask. Use [`FindFirst` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=findfirst) for that:

```
#define FindFolder(Path) \
    Local[0] = FindFirst(Path, faDirectory), \
    Local[0] ? AddBackslash(ExtractFileDir(Path)) + FindGetFileName(Local[0]) : Path

[Files]
Source: "{#FindFolder("..\packages\PackagesA*")}\*.*"; DestDir: "{app}"; \
    flags: recursesubdirs
```

If you add [`SaveToFile`](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=savetofile) call to the end of the script:

```
#expr SaveToFile(AddBackslash(SourcePath) + "Preprocessed.iss")
```

... you will see that the above code resolves to:

```
[Files]
Source: "..\packages\PackageA1.2.0\*.*"; DestDir: "{app}"; flags: recursesubdirs
```

If no such folder is found, the code resolves to:

```
[Files]
Source: "..\packages\PackageA*\*.*"; DestDir: "{app}"; flags: recursesubdirs
```

... and the compiler will then fail with *"No files found matching ..."*.

Comment: where exactly will I be calling SavetoFile and what is the Preprocessed.iss file ? Apology for my dumb question

Comment: *"the end of the script"* - The `SaveToFile` will generate the `Preprocessed.iss` - It's just for debugging, so that you can see what the `FindFolder` evaluates to.

Comment: your solution has worked as intended. Additionally, one more question... Is it possible to find the most recent folder of the package for instance if i have PackageA1.0.1 & Package1.0.4 but use only the Package1.0.4. Is it it possible to do ?

Comment: Well everything is possible. But this is a way more complicated to implement.

Comment: OK that's good to know. I will now crack on with it then. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sorry for hijacking this question again. But was wondering if the macro you provided above can be used to when trying to include a script file such as   shown edit 2. Is that correct way to do so ? And if you require then i can post it as a new question.

Comment: It should be `#include FindFolder('..\..\..\packages\ScriptPreRequisites*') + "\DotNetDependencies.iss"`

Comment: if you dont mind me asking. could you explain as why the different behaviour in the syntax here ?

Comment: Sorry, that's not something I can explain in a limited space of a comment. If you are interested, ask a proper question - But basically within `#` you are using a completely different language (the preprocessor)

Comment: Thanks for teh short answer. However i have asked it as another question  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53779355/why-preprocessor-behave-differntly-when-include-a-script-file-and-a-source-file)