# Why preprocessor behaves differently in #include directive then in [Files] section Inno Setup script

Tags: inno-setup, preprocessor

Was trying to understand the difference between a syntax that would include another script file and a source file in Inno Setup script while using macros to search and find files.

I have tried to use `FindFolder` function from [Find a directory using wildcard in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53760991/850848#53761707):

```
#define FindFolder(Path) \
    Local[0] = FindFirst(Path, faDirectory), \
    Local[0] ? AddBackslash(ExtractFileDir(Path)) + FindGetFileName(Local[0]) : Path
```

Like this:

```
#include "{#FindFolder('..\..\..\packages\ScriptPreRequisites*')}\DotNetDependencies.iss"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within `#` you are in the "realm" of [Inno Setup preprocessor](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/).

There are two ways to enter preprocessor realm.

- Full line syntax:

  ```
  #directive args
  ```
- And inline syntax:

  ```
  {#directive args}
  ```

  The inline syntax is almost exclusively used for [`emit` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/) - `{#emit <expression>}`. And for this reason there's a shorthand format, with the `emit` omitted: `{#<expression>}`.

The inline syntax is useful when you want to use preprocessor expression outside of preprocessor realm. Like in normal Inno Setup sections (or in Pascal Script code):

```
[Files]
Source: "{#FindFolder("..\packages\PackagesA*")}\*.*"; DestDir: "{app}"; \
    flags: recursesubdirs
```

---

Though in [`#include` preprocessor directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=include), you are already in the preprocessor realm. And there, the `{#xxx}` syntax is invalid (it might even have a different [valid] meaning theoretically, but actually curly brackets have no use in preprocessor).

The syntax of `#include` directive is:

```
#include <expression>
```

The preprocessor uses C-like [expression syntax](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=expressions). So your expression in this case is:

```
FindFolder('..\..\..\packages\ScriptPreRequisites*') + '\DotNetDependencies.iss'
```